# Add [mesos] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

What it is:

> [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) abstracts CPU, memory, storage, and other compute resources away from machines (physical or virtual), enabling fault-tolerant and elastic distributed systems to easily be built and run effectively.
>
> Mesos is built using the same principles as the Linux kernel, only at a different level of abstraction. The Mesos kernel runs on every machine and provides applications (e.g., Hadoop, Spark, Kafka, Elastic Search) with API’s for resource management and scheduling across entire datacenter and cloud environments.Apache Mesos

Sampling of questions that could use this tag:

- [Apache Mesos Vs. Apache CloudStack](https://serverfault.com/q/623803/219235)
- [Installing Apache Mesos on CentOS or RHEL](https://serverfault.com/q/542493/219235)
- [Mesos kills container when requests increase](https://serverfault.com/q/660533/219235)
- [running mesos-master in docker container - cannot see containers IP from other hosts](https://serverfault.com/q/615153/219235)
- [Is it possible to let a web application use the combined hardware resources of a few server machines using Apache Mesos?](https://serverfault.com/q/610421/219235)
- [Does CoreOS have a cluster aware job scheduler?](https://serverfault.com/q/596595/219235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added tag [apache-mesos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-mesos).  I'm copying that text into the tag summary and wiki so it has something, but feel free to improve on that.

Comment: FYI, on Stack Overflow, the tag is simply [`mesos`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesos); not sure if you want to keep the `apache-` prefix or not.

Comment: @MishaBrukman mesos is it's synonym, so we should be fine.